# How to keep domain model separate from repository and enable migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I've a scenario where the project structure as following

1. DomainModels
2. Repository --ReferenceTo 'DomainModels'
3. Curator --ReferenceTo 'Repository'
4. MVC project   -ReferenceTo 'Curator'

Now the problem is If I keep My DbContext in DomainModel which I'm supposed to keep, I cann't enable Db Migrations.

-- The only solution I've come across is to give the reference of 'DomainModels' to 'MVC projects'
using Enable-Migration MigrationName SomeAdditionalParameter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this a problem? I have a Data project which contains the models and DbContext. My web and business projects reference this. When I run the Add-Migration step, I just select the Data project in the project dropdown and it uses the connection string in the web.config in the web project. It works well and I have no problems.

Comment: In Visual Studio, bring up the Nuget Console. There is a "Default Project" dropdown on the top right. Change this to to your Domain project. See this image for an example: http://lh4.ggpht.com/-oFcFkEWoVfs/ThCAkpKB5fI/AAAAAAAAAi8/vmlS87ChT6Q/nuget-console_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png?imgmax=800

Comment: Can you please add that the project has to be selected from the Package manage window, SO that It's not confusing

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I meant add your comment to your answer, so that people will understand that It has to be selected from PackageManagers. You have not specified that from where that the project has to be selected